# Swift package Manager missing library after wrap

Tags: swift-package-manager

I'm trying to generate a wrapper around a C library for Swift but when I import it into my Xcode project I'm getting an error that

> Missing required module 'Clibsodium'

I'm not sure where it's trying to get that name from.  My wrapper has this for the Package.swift

```swift
// swift-tools-version:4.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Sodium",
    pkgConfig: "libsodium",
    providers: [
        .brew(["libsodium"]),
        .apt(["libsodium-dev"])
    ]
)
```

And then my module.modulemap looks like so:

```
module Sodium [system] {
  header "shim.h"
  link "sodium"
  export *
}
```

and shim.h just includes the proper header:

```c
#ifndef CLIB_SWIFT_SODIUM
#define CLIB_SWIFT_SODIUM

#ifdef __APPLE__
    #include "/usr/local/include/sodium.h"
#else
    #include "/usr/include/sodium.h"
#endif

#endif
```

On my mac, if I run `pkg-config --libs libsodium` it says this:

> -L/usr/local/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.16/lib -lsodium

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the defining the **Clibsodium** lib as an explicit module. Doing that you can import it via the Sodium framework like **import Sodium.Clibsodium** and fixing with that the missing **Missing required module 'Clibsodium'**

I inspired my solution on:

> In order to import C library into Swift, it first need to be be
>   declared as a module. Declaration takes the form of a module map — a
>   file describing headers to import and static libraries to link with.
>   The resulting module may be imported into Swift (natively) and
>   Objective-C (using @import keyword).
>
> This way of embedding C library
>   into a framework will work for you in most cases (learn more about
>   this approach here and there). It is totally legit as long as you’re
>   developing some internal framework or simply modularising your
>   application into separate parts. However, it doesn’t work well when
>   you need to ship your library to external users via Carthage,
>   Cocoapods or as a binary. The main reason being that the resulting
>   framework is not portable between computers. When undergoing
>   compilation, your resulting framework is bound to the current location
>   of headers and libraries from module map on your computer. You can use
>   it right away in your project but should you try to send it to
>   somebody else they will not be able to link it to a project because
>   files referenced by module map are no longer accessible.

from [this](https://badootech.badoo.com/bundling-c-library-in-swift-framework-3d9dae950774) article where you can find step by step how to achieve it with the advantage and disadvantage of this approach.

Basically what you need to do is:

- Create the **Sodium.modulemap** file and add it to the root of your project
- Inside **Sodium.modulemap** you can define the Clibsodium library as an explicit module like:

  ```
  framework module Sodium {
      umbrella header "Sodium.h"

      explicit module Clibsodium {
          private header "version.h"
          private header "crypto_pwhash_argon2id.h"
          private header "export.h"
          private header "core.h"
          private header "crypto_aead_aes256gcm.h"
          private header "crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305.h"
          private header "crypto_aead_xchacha20poly1305.h"
          private header "crypto_auth.h"
          private header "crypto_auth_hmacsha256.h"
          private header "crypto_auth_hmacsha512.h"
          private header "crypto_auth_hmacsha512256.h"
          private header "crypto_box.h"
          private header "crypto_box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305.h"
          private header "crypto_core_hsalsa20.h"
          private header "crypto_core_hchacha20.h"
          private header "crypto_core_salsa20.h"
          private header "crypto_core_salsa2012.h"
          private header "crypto_core_salsa208.h"
          private header "crypto_generichash.h"
          private header "crypto_generichash_blake2b.h"
          private header "crypto_hash.h"
          private header "crypto_hash_sha256.h"
          private header "crypto_hash_sha512.h"
          private header "crypto_kdf.h"
          private header "crypto_kdf_blake2b.h"
          private header "crypto_kx.h"
          private header "crypto_onetimeauth.h"
          private header "crypto_onetimeauth_poly1305.h"
          private header "crypto_pwhash.h"
          private header "crypto_pwhash_argon2i.h"
          private header "crypto_scalarmult.h"
          private header "crypto_scalarmult_curve25519.h"
          private header "crypto_secretbox.h"
          private header "crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305.h"
          private header "crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305.h"
          private header "crypto_shorthash.h"
          private header "crypto_shorthash_siphash24.h"
          private header "crypto_sign.h"
          private header "crypto_sign_ed25519.h"
          private header "crypto_stream.h"
          private header "crypto_stream_chacha20.h"
          private header "crypto_stream_salsa20.h"
          private header "crypto_stream_xsalsa20.h"
          private header "crypto_verify_16.h"
          private header "crypto_verify_32.h"
          private header "crypto_verify_64.h"
          private header "randombytes.h"
          private header "randombytes_internal_random.h"
          private header "randombytes_sysrandom.h"
          private header "runtime.h"
          private header "utils.h"
       }

    export *
    module * { export * }
  }
  ```
- Sodium.modulemap should not be added to any target and must be specified in **Build Settings — Packaging — Module Map (MODULEMAP_FILE) = $SRCROOT/GifSwift/GifSwift.modulemap**
- Clibsodium files must be added to framework target as Private Header and linked static library (libsodium-x.a)
- Replace the **import Clibsodium** statements with **Sodium.Clibsodium**

Now you can use the Sodium framework in any project without having the missing module error because Sodium will look for the library inside the .framework container